# How to use HTTP Live Streaming protocol in iPhone SDK 3.0

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, appstore-approval, http-live-streaming

I have developed on IPhone application and submitted to App store. But my application got rejected based on below criteria.

> Thank you for submitting your yyyyyyyy
>   application.  We have reviewed your
>   application and have determined that
>   it cannot be posted to the App Store
>   at this time because it is not using
>   the HTTP Live Streaming protocol to
>   broadcast streaming video. HTTP Live
>   Streaming is required when streaming
>   video feeds over the cellular network,
>   in order to have an optimal user
>   experience and utilize cellular best
>   practices. This protocol automatically
>   determines bandwidth available to
>   users and adjusts the bandwidth
>   appropriately, even as bandwidth
>   streams change.  This allows you the
>   flexibility to have as many streams as
>   you like, as long as 64 kbps is set as
>   the baseline feed.

In my apps I have to stream prerecorded m4v and mp3 files from my server. I used MPMoviePlayerController to stream and play those videos / audio.

How to implement the HTTP Live Streaming Protocol in my apps? Also can I get some sample code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

There are many documents about Apple's HTTP Live Streaming:

- [HTTP Live Streaming Overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [IETF HTTP Live Streaming Internet-Draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-07)

There are many encoder devices claim to support this protocol e.g.,

- Inlet's Spinnaker, acquired by Cisco and renamed to [Cisco Media Processor Family](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/video/ps11488/ps11791/ps11806/overview.html).

For a software solution, please give a visit to [Wowza](http://www.wowzamedia.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below notes specified in [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

****Important: iPhone and iPad apps that send large amounts of audio or video data over cellular networks are required to use HTTP Live Streaming.****