# App Rejected for not using HTTP Live Streaming Protocol

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, app-store, http-live-streaming

Do I need to make any code-level changes to play my videos over HTTP Live Streaming protocol? or is it more a server issue, where i need to re-encode the videos etc?

> We've reviewed your application, but
>   cannot post this version to the App
>   Store because it is not using the HTTP
>   Live Streaming protocol, which is
>   required for broadcasting streaming
>   video over the cellular networks for
>   longer than ten minutes. We have
>   included additional details below to
>   help explain the issue, and hope
>   you’ll consider revising and
>   resubmitting your application.

Here is how I am playing the video. It is just pointing to a CloudFront URL:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    STVideo *mySTVideo;
    mySTVideo = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    moviePlayerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:mySTVideo.video_url]];

    moviePlayerViewController.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"st-screen.png"]];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayerViewController];

    [moviePlayerViewController release];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: What was the exact rejection message?

Comment: updated my question w/ rejection msg

Comment: Could you post the code you're using to play the video, including the way you construct the URL.

Comment: @Shaeeham Alam, I have faced same problem and got rejected same reason. You have to implement HTTP Live streaming and solved this problem. And you need to work some server side work also. see my question:" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719958/how-to-use-http-live-streaming-protocol-in-iphone-sdk-3-0 ".

Comment: I don't see any code-level changes you have made. Looks like its all server side?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It all seems quite straight forward to me.  You are playing a stream for more than 10 minutes across the cell network without using [HTTP live streaming](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-04).  Having read through Apple's [documentation on live streaming](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH1-DontLinkElementID_29), I would guess the issue is entirely server side i.e. if you point the media player object at a live streaming URL, it'll figure it out automatically.