# Playing a video via HTTP streaming inside an app

Tags: php, ios, http-streaming

I need to play a video inside my app. The video will reside on a server. I have seen in some places if you do a server interaction to view a video it should be supported with HTTP streaming. Has anyone submitted an iOS app without supporting HTTP streaming to buffer the video?

Is there any PHP script available to stream the video?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH1-DontLinkElementID_39 According to it, I think we need a stream segmenter?

Comment: Another followed thread. Says the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623136/app-rejected-for-not-using-http-live-streaming-protocol

Comment: @Basic HTTP live streaming and progressive download are two different things.

Comment: @Jasarien I hadn't realised OP meant "HTTP Live Streaming".

Comment: @Josh Cashwell why did you remove the part "Also, I want to know if my app will get accepted if I open that server URL in the external media player in iOS which will be annoying to the user but is another good option."? This is another part I need to know as well.

Comment: First, because you were combining too many questions into one post. Second, and more importantly, because "Will my app be approved?" is both speculative and [off-topic for SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131388/would-questions-about-app-store-approval-be-appropriate-for-so).