# Create a UIbutton and UIImageview in UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, uitextview

I have a UITextview in my Screen,I created textview in drag and drop on screen, now i want to add button to last (end of the text in text view )of the textview then how can i do that ??

i have been try

```
[super viewDidLoad];
 SelectInvestiList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[InvestiList count]]; 


AppDelegate *appDeleg = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

textViewInvest.text=nil;

UIButton*button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
[button setTitle:@"test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[textViewInvest addSubview:button];

NSMutableString *prev=[[NSMutableString alloc] init];
if (appDeleg.chiefCompText != nil) {
    prev=(NSMutableString *) textViewInvest.text;
    [prev appendString:(NSMutableString *) appDeleg.chiefCompText];
    textViewInvest.text=[prev capitalizedString];

}

if (appDeleg.vitalText != nil) {
    prev=(NSMutableString *)textViewInvest.text;
    [prev appendString:(NSMutableString *) appDeleg.vitalText];
    textViewInvest.text=[prev capitalizedString];

}
```

but that not work ..

Comment: It looks that you didn't properly _connect_ `IBOutlet` of view's owner (property `textViewInvest`) to your `UITextView`.

Comment: no i connect well bcoz i put text in it from web Services

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719958/how-to-use-http-live-streaming-protocol-in-iphone-sdk-3-0 u r invited to this chat pls check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 20)];
        [btn setTitle:@"Ram" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        //[self.view addSubview:btn];
        [textview addSubview:btn];
set the button frame according to your text in textview.
```

Comment: no.. i has tried your code but button is not show in my textview

Comment: Its working in my app.I checked three to four times.U allocate textview with frame properly.I added textview to the screen by code.

Comment: @S Rama Rao if i also added textview to screen by code than it's work but i need to dread and drop textview.. so that not show up button

Comment: ya.. but button put programicaly

Comment: check this edited answer that is added on my app when textview is added in interface builder and button is added to textview programettically

Comment: @S Rama can u tell me how can i get size of end of textview text , the text is generated dynemically meance not fix –

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9956/discussion-between-s-rama-rao-and-ravi)

Comment: is that button included in scrolling view. means when u write many text into textview at that time button will not be the part of scrollview I hope so

Answer (score 3):

Iam not sure whether you are using Interface builder.

U can try this

```
UIButton *myButton  =   [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
myButton.frame      =   CGRectMake(0.0, 100.0, 50.0, 30.0);
[yourTextView addSubview:myButton];
```

Comment: no.. i has tried your code but button is not show in my textview

Comment: @ravi: This code is correct. I am not sure what you are doing wrong

Comment: @ravi: Don't use `textViewInvest.text=nil;` instead do `textViewInvest.text=@"";` in your code.

Comment: @ParthBhatt ya it's work now but can u tell me that how i can find end of the text pixel in Textview ??if text length is not fix ?? bcoz i cant to add button at end of text

Comment: @ravi: Sorry but I didn't get what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @ParthBhatt see in my Qsn, i want to add button on text view after print that appDeleg.chiefCompText text

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9959/discussion-between-parth-bhatt-and-ravi)

Comment: hi ravi, yourTextView.contentSize.height will give you the height of the text/content in your textview.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you should mention the `type` of button while you are adding through code. I just  got it working with this:

```
UIButton*button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
[button setTitle:@"test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[yourTextView addSubview:button];
```

Comment: no.. i has tried your code but button is not show in my textview

Comment: @ravi, that's unusual, i tested it just before posting those lines. I hope you are putting these lines of code in `viewDidLoad` ?

Comment: @ravi, yes just went through it, is the `textViewInvest` behaving like it should ? Does changing the .text of textView change the text ? Only thing i can think of is that `textViewInvest` is not connected to the IB. And sometimes using code before `[super viewDidLoad];` helps. Just check if it's connected properly.

Answer (score 1):

Check it out dear,  it works for me always.

```
for (id view in [textView subviews]) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
            UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,35)];
            [view addSubview:btn];
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is id here ?? and you put button in the UIScrollView ??

Comment: how much programming experience do u have in iOS development. paste this code in ur project it will work dear

Comment: around 5 month no dear that's not Work

Comment: id is a datatype which is able to hold any type of object, more detail google it

Comment: I tested it for UIImage and it always work. U should make proper button and then add it. it will work. I bet u.

Comment: for (id view in [textView subviews]) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
            
            [view addSubview:[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"noimage.png"]]];
        }
    }

Comment: can u tell me how can i get size of end of textview text , the text is generated dynemically meance not fix

Comment: - (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{ NSInteger i= [textView.text length]; }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9957/discussion-between-gaurav-d-sharma-and-ravi)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. Here iam creating textview also. This worked fine for me.

```
UITextView *yourTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 400.0)];
yourTextView.backgroundColor    =   [UIColor grayColor];
[self.view addSubview:yourTextView];

UIButton *myButton  =   [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
myButton.frame      =   CGRectMake(0.0, 100.0, 50.0, 30.0);
[myButton setTitle:@"GO" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[yourTextView addSubview:myButton];
```

Comment: Edit your old answer with this, there is an edit option below your answer that you already posted.

Comment: @mrithu i cant add TextView programically

Answer (score 1):

It will work.

```
 for (id view in [textView subviews]) {
            if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
                UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]; 
                [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 20)]; 
                [btn setTitle:@"Ram" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                [view addSubview:btn];
            }
        }
```